# Docker - Springboot app container cannot connect to 2019 SQL Server container using docker-compose, TCP/IP connection error

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, tcp

I'm working with Springboot app and 2019 mssql server docker containers, I tried to connect springboot app container to mssql server container but I got the issue below

```
2022-10-28 15:58:32.420  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table account_roles 
       drop constraint FK70s9enq5d1oywl7v8vis5ke5w
2022-10-28 15:58:33.049  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-28 15:59:03.596 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:288) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2720) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:761) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3180) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2833) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2671) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1640) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:936) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar!/:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:18) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[spring-boot-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[spring-boot-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[spring-boot-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[spring-boot-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2022-10-28 15:59:03.599  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2022-10-28 15:59:03.600 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
2022-10-28 15:59:03.610 ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2022-10-28 15:59:03.611  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2022-10-28 15:59:03.613  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-10-28 15:59:03.630  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-10-28 15:59:03.654 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

- I have tried to research how to enable TCP/IP connection for sql server container, but I got the answer is that TCP/IP connection default is enable so I do not know why I still got this error, also I tried to change my connection url many ways but still got the same issue
- I have tried to build springboot app separately (not built into a container) and connected it to mssql server container successfully but I don't why I failed to use docker-compose to connect them

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mssql
  mssql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "Rubikcube200@"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Below is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost,1433;databaseName=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Rubikcube200@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/spring-boot-docker.jar spring-boot-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/spring-boot-docker.jar"]
```

Please help me, Thank you guys a lot!

- I have tried to change connection string many ways but still got the same issue
- Also try to expose the port 1433 on mssql server container in docker-compose file

Here is my project github link, could you guys please take a look? Thank you a lot! https://github.com/zangvu/docker-springboot

Comment: check for containers if that sql container is up and running.

Comment: _I'm working with Springboot app and 2019 mssql server docker containers_ ... so the Springboot app is not inside the SQL Server container? Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs so from a networking perspective `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` each point to the container itself. Your Springboot app container doesn't have SQL Server running inside it so there's no SQL service listening on `localhost,1433`. Your SQL Server container is named `mssql`... have you tried `mssql,1433` yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I try changing connection string into `jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433;databaseName=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;` but got the same issue and I have connected to sql server container through mssql management studio 18 (Server name: localhost, login: sa, pass: Rubikcube200@) successfully so I think it is not due to using wrong server name :(

Comment: @muhammedozbilici of course, sql container is on when I run docker-compose up command :(

Comment: Here is my project github link, could you guys please take a look? Thank you a lot!
https://github.com/zangvu/docker-springboot

Comment: SSMS works on the Docker host using `localhost` because you're publishing the mssql containers port to localhost with `ports: - "1433:1433"`

Comment: Perhaps there's something else going on here... does the Springboot container try to connect to SQL Server before that service has actually finished starting up? The "depends" check in the compose file only tests that the linux kernel is responding in the container but the SQL Server service itself can take tens of seconds to attach, test and start up each of the system and user databases. Has it finished starting up (in the container's Docker log) before Springboot attempts to connect?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have already restarted springboot app container after mssql container is up but get the same issue :(

Comment: @AlwaysLearning more info, i run springboot app on my computer (not build it into a container) and connect to mssql container successfully but i dont why in this case it failed

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried to add container_name and use it like a host `jdbc:sqlserver://<container_name>:1433;databaseName=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;` then it works thank you a lot!